# HP P4000 LeftHand Setup: Configure a VIP (Virtual IP)

Tags: ip, hp, ip-routing, lefthand

I'm trying to setup a HP LeftHand Storage System (2x p4300) in our testlab.

As I have no router (but only a Catalyst 2960-S switch) in the testlab: Is there a way to setup a VIP (Virtual IP) to enable redundancy? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built-in feature of LeftHand SAN's. Router and switch support is not needed. If you went through the start-up wizard in the CMC, you should already have a VIP.

If not, right-click the name of your management group in the CMC and pick `New Cluster`. Walk through the wizard and at the end you will have a VIP.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The P4000 SAN Solution Userguide is somehow misleading regarding the Virtual IP. But you're right, the CMC wizard will create all necessary stuff, when a unassigned IP is entered in the VIP dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the SAN/IQ software and part of setting up the cluster - assuming you want to configure the VIP on the iSCSi network.

Assuming you already setup the network correctly on the nodes, from the CMC, you can choose the option to create a cluster. The first step in the wizard that follows is the enter the VIP of the cluster. The VIP is the IP that you configure your iSCSI initiators to use to connect to the volumes created on the LeftHand. With 2 nodes, you will probably look at Network RAID1 to mirror the data between the two nodes to provide data redundancy across the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

...Or multi-site cluster allowing you to use 2 VIP's since the SAN has a MGMT network and (assuming 10GBt NIC for iSCSI in a different network VLAN) ,

So let's say a VIP 10.10.1.10/24 (LAN) and a VIP 10.10.2.10/24 (iSCSI) . Network bond is reccomended ..

Multiste cluster indeed mean have more VIP .